# copyplist failed with exit code 71

Tags: iphone, xcode, build, plist, adhoc

I have an iPhone app that's shipping (*vConqr* - you should go and buy it :-) ).
I build the project on several different machines, including a colleague's, and it's been working fine.
However, just recently, on my second dev machine my build fails every time with the error:

`/Developer/Library/Xcode/Plug-ins/CoreBuildTasks.xcplugin/Contents/Resources/copyplist Entitlements.plist --outdir /Code/iPhone/VirtualConquest/build/Debug-iphonesimulator/VirtualConquest.app`

`error: can't exec '/Developer/Library/Xcode/Plug-ins/CoreBuildTasks.xcplugin/Contents/Resources/copyplist' (No such file or directory)`

I've reinstalled XCode - twice! (the second time I deleted the files under /Developer/Library/Xcode first).
I've deleted my source tree and checked out of source control fresh.
The error persists.

The Entitlements.plist file has been there for a couple of weeks, since I started my last beta programme. I can't be sure, but I suspect I had not compiled on my second dev machine since it was added. However, as well as my primary dev machine, it also all builds fine on my colleagues machine, so I'm baffled what the difference can be.

I've Googled for the error, but either my Google-Fu is bunk or this is not a common error - I've found no relevant hits.

This is really frustrating, not least because I use my second machine as a soak test/ continuous integration machine.

Anyone come across the same thing, or have any other suggestions?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I hit this problem and chased it down to a problem with my ruby install - well not really a problem but anyway

Solved it by doing a symlink to the correct place for my ruby install

sudo ln -s /opt/local/bin/ruby /usr/bin/ruby

Hope this helps someone as it drove me insane! Also, may not be your ruby install this file just loads the core libraries so just run the file, if it exists, to track it down

Comment: Thanks for the response Jimmy. I did do a Ruby install at around the same time, IIRC - that may well have been it!

Comment: By all means, do not mess with /usr/bin. Just remove /opt/local/bin from your PATH when you want to build this software to avoid any MacPorts interference.

Answer (score 1):

yeah, I have this from a custom ruby install, a more universal fix is:

sudo ln -s `which ruby` /usr/bin/ruby

Answer (score 1):

From here:
http://fr.ivolo.us/posts/when-rails-devs-go-iphone

Open copyplist in your favorite text editor, and change

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby
```

to

```
#!/usr/local/bin/bash
```

I had to just use
    #!/usr/local/bin/ruby
to get it to use my system install of ruby, but I imagine you could enter any of your RVM ruby paths as well.

Answer (score 0):

That file exists on my machine. Try doing a third clean reinstall of Xcode (after deleting the entire /Developer tree - the Xcode install should re-add that whole thing). Then immediately check to see if that file exists, as it should.

Comment: The file was there the first time, and was in the folder I deleted. It was re-added after my second (clean) install. I don't think the issue is with the plugin itself. Interestingly, if I delete the Entitlements.plist file it works (although not for ad-hoc builds, of course)

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me but it was related to a corrupt language strings file.  I had an extra character in one of the strings (see the example)

x"english string" = "international string";

Answer (score 0):

In my case the problem was much simpler:

I deleted a few Localization.strings files from the SVN and forgot to remove them from the Xcode-project too.

I removed them from the project and now its working.