# build problem in xcode

Tags: iphone, xcode

On all the sample projects from apple's site (like Simple Drill Down) when I do a compile I get "copystrings failed with exit code 71".

And old project of mine compiles.  Seems to be be an issue with localized strings:
"copystrings failed with exit code 71"  My old project doesn't have any localized strings of course.

here is a screenshot:
http://img.skitch.com/20090722-rn5gbps4f9endan6xpa5gegmbp.png

The error also indicates XCode can't find copystrings, but here it is:

here is an "ls" of the directory in question:
pswenson@zeppelin /Developer/Library/Xcode/Plug-ins/CoreBuildTasks.xcplugin/Contents/Resources]$ ls copystrings
-rwxrwxr-x  1 root  admin  7689 Jul  2 17:52 copystrings
[pswenson@zeppelin /Developer/Library/Xcode/Plug-ins/CoreBuildTasks.xcplugin/Contents/Resources]$

any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What version of Xcode are you running? Because the newer projects will require Xcode 3.0 and up to compile

Or it could be related to: [copyplist failed with exit code 71](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/384962/copyplist-failed-with-exit-code-71)

Comment: I'm using 3.1.4 (prerelease for 3.1)

Comment: Ok try the link that I posted to see if that helps any

Comment: It's the ruby issue as you suggested in your link.  I figured this out a couple days ago as well.  Lesson is: don't mess with the built in install of ruby.  If you want a new install of ruby, leave the old one alone.