# Build error 71 on Xcode

Tags: objective-c, ruby, xcode

I've been working on a GUI program for a while now, and I just can't get it to compile correctly, I am constantly receiving the following error -

> Command /Developer/Library/Xcode/Plug-ins/CoreBuildTasks.xcplugin/Contents/Resources/copystrings failed with exit code 71

I've done some searching around to try to find a solution, and found a question on StackOverflow with the same problem over at - [copyplist failed with exit code 71](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/384962/copyplist-failed-with-exit-code-71) - however I've tried following the steps provided as the best answer, to no avail, and I've had no luck trying anything else.

I do think, however, that this is a problem with my Ruby install, because I did some installing only a short time back.

I've tired re-installing Xcode, deleting the Developer folder and getting Xcode to rebuild, and a number of terminal tricks to try to fix the problem. At the moment I'm unable to compile.

Comment: possible duplicate of [copyplist failed with exit code 71](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/384962/copyplist-failed-with-exit-code-71)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everytime I had copystrings failing it was due to a syntax error. Make sure every string starts with quotation marks and ends with quotation marks, make sure every string assignment has a semicolon at the end.

```
"foo" = "bar";
```

Also watch out for quotation mark escaping:

```
"foo" = "bar with \"escaped\" quotation marks";
```

For me, it was missing semicolons most of the time.

Comment: Hey man, sorry for the late response - I was away, I looked through my code, and even created a new project without edits, and I still got the error :/

Comment: I ended up re-installing OS X, must have messed up my Ruby instillation, but it's all fixed now.